# Best partition for stats table

Tags: mysql, database-performance, database-partitioning

We have a large stats table which logs hits per day, per product.

```
   date      | datetime
   productid | int
   hits      | int
   channel   | enum
```

About 200M rows+

We have two ways of querying this date - It always has productid in the WHERE (or multiple productIDs), then optionally with a date specified too. Most of the queries will have both.

We allow users to query on the usual date 'buckets' eg Today/Yesterday/Last 7 days/Last month/Last 3 months/This year/Last year. They can also pick arbitrary dates.

So I'm tossing up between partitioning on date vs productid. My thinking is that if we're querying on a number of productIDs at once (using IN()) then this could mean spanning multiple partitions. However, as most of the queries will be within a year, that partitioning by date would be best?

As most queries are for short periods (eg days/weeks), perhaps we have something like:

Last 3 months Last 3-6 months Last 6-12 months Then yearly buckets.

Our data goes back to 2005.

Thanks for advice.

Comment: Not to say that you are wrong to do so, but why exactly are you proposing partitions? And see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint (have sunglasses to hand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by making sure the datatypes are as small as practical.  Will there be a billion productids?  `INT` is 4 bytes.  `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` is 3 bytes and allows values between 0 and 16 million.  Etc.

You have some combination of these?

```
AND productid = 123  (or, equivalently, productid IN (123))  -- (1)

AND productid IN (234,345,456)  -- (2)

AND date >= '2020...'
AND date <  '2020...' + INTERVAL 7 DAY    -- (3)
```

Your "last month" shorthand can easily be turned into a date range with the starting date and that `+ INTERVAL 1 MONTH`.

For AND clause (1) or (1 and 3) or (2):  `PRIMARY KEY(productid, date)` is optimal even without partitioning.  If that pair is unique, then do that.  (It sounds like it is.)

(3 alone) and (2 and 3) are trickier.

(3) needs `INDEX(date)`

Do you need to delete "old" stats?  If so, then `PARTITION BY RANGE(date)` is strongly recommended.  It lets you `DROP PARTITION` (very fast) instead of `DELETE`.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

With that partitioning, you get some two-dimensional help for (2 and 3).  Or the optimizer might be smart enough to hop around the table with the PK I recommended.

I would build yearly buckets before 2020, then monthly starting with Jan, 2020.  And I would not combine monthly into yearly in the future because it blocks the table "too much".  Partitions:

```
1  pre-2005 (empty) (see link for reason)
15 2005..2019  (Thanks for providing the '2005')
11(so far)  2020, jan..nov
1  "future" (see link)
(28 currently, but growing)
```

and have a nightly attempt to make a new 'month' partition *just before it is needed*.  (Do not pre-build lots of partitions.)

(Note:  The years+months partitioning is a one-time task.  All future partitions are "month", and I avoided combining months into years.  And you won't hit any limits on partitioning in the lifetime of the computer or the project.)

Do they never test `channel`?  Do they never do `SUM(hits) .. GROUP BY`?  Those would lead to more discussion.

"Locality of reference"...

The data may occupy 10GB?  How much RAM do you have?  What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  Do users *usually* read "recent" data"?  The answers interact to predict how much I/O is needed, hence how fast queries run.

The indexing and partitioning I recommended above is aimed at

- Very low I/O if *all* queries are for "recent" data.
- Reasonably low I/O even if there are *occasional* "old" queries.  (It sounds like this is your case.)
- Will "work" (at some speed) even if dates are scattered over all time.

You may have noticed that I cluster primarily on `productid`.  Here's the impact:

- 2D indexing is tricky; one dimension needs to go first in the PK; the other can be via partitioning.
- If there are, say, 10K products, then the "inserts" will have 10K "hot spots.  That is, there will be 10K 16KB blocks in the buffer_pool essentially all the time, ready to receive the next reading.  That's a mere 160MB, which is doubtless a small fraction of the buffer_pool_size.  Hence no I/O for the inserts.

11 months of data is probably less than 1GB?  Again, that is likely to stay live in the buffer_pool for all the "recent" queries.  (Locality of reference; "partition pruning").

Comment: Thanks @Rick, Your observations are correct, except we never just query by date. We currently have a PK set on (productID, date, channel) as we often group by channel as you discussed.

So I will try the partitions based on date range. I need to work what advantage we have on creating monthly partitions vs yearly as that's obviously more maintenance, etc and we potentially hit limits on how many partitions. So I'll try both and see if there's much performance boost.

Comment: @Ben - Good.  Years through 2019 plus months after that -- This will not hit any hard limits, nor any practical limits on partitioning, before the computer dies of old age.  (Think of how few 2005-vintage computers are still running!)